# How do you set delegate to a view controller when using a factory pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, factory-method

I have a `UIViewController` and in the viewDidLoad method I have a factory method that returns views.

I am trying to set the UIViewController to be the delegate of these different views. However, every view has a different delegate, and when I actually call the factory method it just returns a UIView. The UIView of course has no knowledge of a delegate.

I cannot very well put the `delegate = ViewController` in the ViewFactory itself because that would mean it would have have knowledge of my ViewController which is terrible. Another thought I had, was that I could just cast all the views to what they actually are so they know about the delegate, but that leaves me duplicating a bunch of code so I was wondering if someone could point me into the right direction here?

ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //This of course would have data to populate it, but I cannot show it here.
    let data = [ViewTemplate]()

    let someView = ViewFactory.getView((data?[currentCount - 1])!)

    //so here is where I thought I could add 
    //someView.delegate
    //but of course it is just a UIView that is returned so it 
    //doesn't know anything about a delegate

    someContainerView.addSubview(someView)
}
}

struct ViewFactory {
static func getView(_ template: ViewTemplate) -> UIView {
    switch template.viewType {
        case .One:
            let bundle = Bundle.main
            let containerView = bundle.loadNibNamed("OneView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! OneView
            containerView.label.text = template.text
            return containerView
        case .Two:
            let bundle = Bundle.main
            let containerView = bundle.loadNibNamed("TwoView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TwoView
            containerView.label.text = template.text
            return containerView
        case .Three:
            let bundle = Bundle.main
            let containerView = bundle.loadNibNamed("ThreeView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ThreeView
            containerView.label.text = template.text
            return containerView
        case .Four:
            let bundle = Bundle.main
            let containerView = bundle.loadNibNamed("FourView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FourView
            containerView.label.text = template.text
            return containerView
        case .Five:
            let bundle = Bundle.main
            let containerView = bundle.loadNibNamed("FiveView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FiveView
            containerView.label.text = template.text
            return containerView
        case .Six:
            let bundle = Bundle.main
            let containerView = bundle.loadNibNamed("SixView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SixView
            containerView.label.text = template.text
            return containerView
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various choices. Here is one approach you could use:

You could make all of your different custom subclasses of `UIView` descend from a common ancestor that has a delegate property. (Let's call it the `CustomView` class.) Then you could make your `ViewFactory` return objects of that type.

Here is your base class for custom views:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
  public weak var delegate: AnyObject?
  //Put any other shared properties/methods of all CustomView objects here
}
```

And your views that are subclasses of CustomView might look like this:

```
class OneView: CustomView {
  //Extra properties/methods for a OneView object
}

class TwoView: CustomView {
  //Extra properties/methods for a TwoView object
}
```

Finally, refactor your ViewFactory to return a view of type `CustomView` instead of a plain `UIView`:

```
struct ViewFactory {
static func getView(_ template: ViewTemplate) -> CustomView {
    switch template.viewType {
        case .One:
            let bundle = Bundle.main
            let containerView = bundle.loadNibNamed("OneView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! OneView
            containerView.label.text = template.text
            return containerView
        //Your other cases...
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it is very close to what I want it to do, but I cannot seem to have different delegates. @Duncan C I have OneView which is now suppose to call `delegate?.oneView(sender.date)`, and twoView would have a different delegate, but of course when I actually use those it says that AnyObject doesn't have the method which makes sense. Any thoughts on how I would get around this? I guess my question is could I override the delegate prop or cast the delegate somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using class inheritance you are probably better using protocols here. A protocol only enforces an interface on a class. You can adopt multiple protocols in a class. You can only inherit from one class.

If you are looking to have common functionality among your delegates then create a protocol for your delegate classes

```
protocol DelegateProtocol {
    func oneView(date: Date)
}
```

Ensure all your delegates adopt this protocol.

```
class MyDelegate : DelegateProtocol {
    func oneView(date: Date) {
    }
    ...
}
```

Create another protocol that holds a reference to this delegate and ensure all your view classes adopt this protocol either through their class definition or a class extension definition

```
class DelegateReferenceProtocol {
    var myDelegate : DelegateProtocol? {get set}
}

class OneView : DelegateReferenceProtocol {
    var myDelegate : DelegateProtocol? {get {} set(value) {}}
    ...
}

extension TwoView : DelegateReferenceProtocol {
    var myDelegate : DelegateProtocol? {get {} set(value) {}}
    ...
}
```

After that as long as you have setup all your view classes to adopt the DelegateReferenceProtocol protocol your viewDidLoad function would be as follows

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, DelegateProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //This of course would have data to populate it, but I cannot show it here.
        let data = [ViewTemplate]()

        let someView = ViewFactory.getView((data?[currentCount - 1])!)
        someView.myDelegate = self

        someContainerView.addSubview(someView)
    }
}
```